# Kettle gpload failed ERROR: permission denied: no privilege to create a readable gpfdist(s) external table

Tags: postgresql, etl, kettle, greenplum

When using kettle greenplum bulkloader and ERROR:  permission denied: no privilege to create a readable gpfdist(s) external table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FlmW.png)

Comment: Please check [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and format your question properly esp the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user running the program in the database needs to have CREATEEXTTABLE privileges.   You can do this with:  ALTER ROLE  CREATEEXTTABLE (type='readable').